# How to run method inside a response function using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to run a method when I get success response from API, but the method dont run. I made a quick example here to show.

The test() function should be executed after i get the response, since its calling another API endpoint. Here is the vue.js code.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#contents",
    data: { 
        id: null,
        details: [],
    },
 
    methods: {

        fetchProductDetails: function(){
            let vue = this;
            axios.post("/api/get-details", {
                id : id
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                vue.details = response.data;
                this.test();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {});
        },
    
        test: function () {
            console.log(app.details);
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        this.fetchProductDetails();
    },

});
```

Comment: Using `function (response)` in your `.then` most likely breaks the scope of `this`. Have you tried using the ES6 arrow syntax?

Comment: Not tested ES6 syntax, my values come out as "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `vue.test()` instead of `this.test()`, just like you use `vue.details = response.data` instead of `this.details = response.data`.

When using an unnamed function in `.then()`, `this` no longer refers to your vue application, but to the unnamed function. You could use ES6 arrow function syntax in order to avoid having to set `this` to a specific variable, as arrow functions use their parent's scope for `this` instead of setting `this` to refer to themselves:

```
axios.post("/api/get-details", { id: this.id })
            .then(response => {
                this.details = response.data;
                this.test();
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error)});
```

Arrow functions (and ES6 in general) are [not supported by IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) however. so you'd need to use Babel to compile it back to something ES5 JavaScript if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: Thanks, i supose i should use this format on api calls in the future then!

Comment: If your target browsers support it (or it's handled by a tool chain that compiles it to older syntax), definitely!

I personally like to use *async/await* instead of then/catch, and *object destructuring* to immediately reach into objects for the key I need as well:

`async fetchProductDetails() { 
  try { 
    const { data } = await axios.post(/api/get-details, { id: this.id }); this.details = data;
    this.test();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}`